# gitlens how to define git path

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My gitlens plugin for VSCode keeps complaining about the old git version.

In the server I have a newer git in a local folder, that prevails in bash because it is
on .bashrc using PATH (alias also tested).

There is in internet a .json setting for the path of git for gitlens.
It doesn't work for the current gitlens version.

How to I make gitlens see my desired local git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessary step:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988854/alter-path-for-vs-code-remote-ssh

(<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>):
Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host